# IP restrict a subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I would like to add a IP restriction based on the URL in my htaccess file. 
This way I can keep my .htaccess file inside my git repo and use the development branch for dev.domain.com and the master branch for the live website on www.domain.com.

I need 1 htaccess since the dev site is a replica of the live site. On the dev site I'd like to have IP restriction. So I need 1 htaccess that looks similar on both environments, but the behaviour of restriction only kicks in on the dev uri.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of restriction, what would it do?

Comment: I need 1 htaccess since the dev site is a replica of the live site.
On the dev site I'd like to have IP restriction.
So I need 1 htaccess that looks similar on both environments, but the behaviour of restriction only kicks in on the dev uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That is why I am looking to have 1 htaccess file which contains a 'switch' to turn on restriction based on the visiting URI.

I've been looking for the same thing for a while, but it doesn't seem to be practically possible. Apache's configuration language knows some conditional blocks, but none to do this as far as I can see.

What I have often ended up doing is specifying two different [`AccessFileName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) properties on the dev and the production server. For example, on the dev server, I would set

```
AccessFileName .htaccess.local
```

the dev server rules would then go into `.htaccess.local`, and the production server ones into ? `htaccess.`

Answer (score 3):

```
order deny,allow
allow from 31.24.232.0/21
allow from 127.0.0.0/20
allow from 192.168.0.0/20
deny from all
```

you can put this in `.htaccess` at document root of your subdomain. but remember to change IPs.

Comment: to block just one IP instead of a range, use `/32`, so e.g. `127.0.0.1/32`

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. 
I cannot use a second .htaccess if I want a full replica of my live environment.
That is why I am looking to have 1 htaccess file which contains a 'switch' to turn on restriction based on the visiting URI.

Comment: @hp well, that is because your question is terribly hazyb - what Deatjh shows is "restricting" access from an IP. What you just said in your comment makes it much clearer what you need. Consider editing it into the question.

Comment: I don't know any directive that restricts based on host name (in `.htaccess`)

Comment: @Pekka you are absolutely right (on rereading the original question I see the gaps I left there).

Comment: @Death me neither, that's why my question ;-)

Comment: I meant I think there is no answer;-) See [this](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/apache-environment-variables-visibility-with-setenv-setenvif-and-rewriterule-directives/)